# Android Studio: Can't get past showProgressbar() screen to new Browse Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I've been having this issue for a while now and I cant figure it out. After spending some time with this issue, it seems like the app is going into realEditProfileActivity where I can edit my profile info but when I press submit it goes into the showproggressbar screen and it just stays there without starting my next activity that is supposed to start which is BrowseActivity.

Here is my code:

Android Manifest

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.flux99"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
        <activity android:name=".BrowseActivity"

            />

        <activity
            android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
            android:label="EditProfileActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".RealEditProfileActivity"
            android:label="RealEditProfileActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.flux99">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

Browse Activity:

```
`package com.example.flux99

import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.annotation.StringRes
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.flux99.ui.Profiles
import com.example.flux99.ui.theme.Teal200
import com.example.flux99.ui.theme.flux99Theme
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import java.io.File

class BrowseActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

    private lateinit var databaseReference : DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var storageReference : StorageReference
    private lateinit var dialog : Dialog
    private lateinit var bioMessage : String
    private var user : User? = null
    private var bitmap : Bitmap? = null
    private lateinit var localFile : File
    private lateinit var uid : String


    enum class BrowseActivity(@StringRes val title: Int) {


        Browse(title = R.string.app_name),
        EditProfile(title = R.string.edit_profile),
        RealEditProfile(title=R.string.real_edit_profile)


    }

    //To do : terminal is saying OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled fore the application to set it to true in the app manifest. check out what that means.



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        setContent {
            flux99Theme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = Teal200
                ) {
                    Flux99()
                }
            }
        }
    }



    @Composable
    fun Flux99(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,

        navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
        ) {

            val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
            // Get the name of the current screen
            val currentScreen = BrowseActivity.valueOf(
                backStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: BrowseActivity.Browse.name
            )
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                CupcakeAppBar(
                    currentScreen = currentScreen,
                    canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
                    navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() }
                )
            }
        ) { innerPadding ->

            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = BrowseActivity.Browse.name,
                modifier = modifier.padding(innerPadding)
            ) {
                composable(route = BrowseActivity.Browse.name) {

                    val profiles = Profiles()
                    getUserData()

                    Column(modifier = modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
                        profiles.ProfileCardGreetingWithImage(user, bitmap)
                       // ButtonExample()

                        Button(onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(BrowseActivity.EditProfile.name)

                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "You clicked the Button.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                        }, colors = ButtonDefaults.textButtonColors( backgroundColor = Color.Blue
                        )) {
                            Text("Edit Profile", color = Color.White)
                        }

                        Button(onClick = {


                                navController.navigate(BrowseActivity.RealEditProfile.name)

                                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "You clicked the Button.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



                        }, colors = ButtonDefaults.textButtonColors( backgroundColor = Color.Blue
                        )) {
                            Text("Real Edit", color = Color.White)
                        }

                    }
//

                }
                composable(route = BrowseActivity.EditProfile.name){
                    val intent = Intent(this@BrowseActivity, EditProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
//move move browseActivit intent in button above to this composable. I think then it will be together in one screen.
                }
                composable(route = BrowseActivity.RealEditProfile.name){
                    val intent = Intent(this@BrowseActivity, RealEditProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
//move move browseActivit intent in button above to this composable. I think then it will be together in one screen.
                }


            }
        }
    }

    private fun getUserData() {
        showProgressBar()
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
        uid = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
        if(uid.isNotEmpty()) {
            databaseReference.child(uid).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                    getUserProfilePhoto()

                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    Toast.makeText(this@BrowseActivity, "Failed to get User Profile data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }

            })
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this@BrowseActivity, "UID is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }

    fun getUserProfilePhoto(){
        showProgressBar()

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Users/$uid.jpg")
        localFile = File.createTempFile("tempImage", "jpg")

        storageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.absolutePath)

            hideProgressBar()

        }.addOnFailureListener{
            hideProgressBar()
            Toast.makeText(this@BrowseActivity, "Failed to get User Profile photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }


    @Composable
    fun CupcakeAppBar(
        currentScreen: BrowseActivity,
        canNavigateBack: Boolean,
        navigateUp: () -> Unit,
        modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
    ) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(stringResource(currentScreen.title)) },
            modifier = modifier,
            navigationIcon = {
                if (canNavigateBack) {
                    IconButton(onClick = navigateUp) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.back_button)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )

    }

    private fun showProgressBar() {

        dialog = Dialog(this@BrowseActivity)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_wait)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog.show()

    }

    private fun hideProgressBar(){

        dialog.dismiss()
    }


}`
```

realeditProfileActivity:

```
`package com.example.flux99

import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.AccountCircle
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Info
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardCapitalization
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue
import com.example.flux99.ui.theme.flux99Theme
import com.example.flux99.ui.Profiles


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons

import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment

import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.*
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.*
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference


class RealEditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var databaseReference : DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var storageReference : StorageReference
    private lateinit var imageUri : Uri
    private lateinit var dialog : Dialog

    private var profile : Profiles? = null

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
            if (uid == null) {
               print("Null thing")
            }
            print(uid)

            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

            setContent {
                flux99Theme() {
                    // A surface container using the
                    // 'background' color from the theme
                    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                        // at below line we are calling
                        // our function for text field.
                        TxtField()
                    }
                }
            }
        }








    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @Composable
    fun TxtField() {
        // we are creating a variable for
        // getting a value of our text field.
        Column(
            // we are using column to align our
            // imageview to center of the screen.
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),

            // below line is used for specifying
            // vertical arrangement.
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,

            // below line is used for specifying
            // horizontal arrangement.
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ){
                var firstName by remember {
                    mutableStateOf("")
                }
                var lastName by remember {
                    mutableStateOf("")
                }
                var bio by remember {
                    mutableStateOf("")
                }
                TextField(
                    value = firstName,
                    onValueChange = {  firstName = it },
                    placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter user name") },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(all = 16.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
                    autoCorrect = true,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                    ),
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = 15.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif),
                maxLines = 2,

                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.AccountCircle, null, tint = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_200))
                },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Info, null, tint = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_200))
                },)
            TextField(
                value = lastName,
                onValueChange = {  lastName = it },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter user name") },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(all = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
                    autoCorrect = true,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                ),
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = 15.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif),
                maxLines = 2,

                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.AccountCircle, null, tint = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_200))
                },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Info, null, tint = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_200))
                },)

            TextField(
                value = bio,
                onValueChange = {  bio = it },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter user bio") },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(all = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
                    autoCorrect = true,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                ),
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = 15.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif),
                maxLines = 2,

                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.AccountCircle, null, tint = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_200))
                },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Info, null, tint = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_200))
                },)

            val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid

            Button(onClick = {

                    showProgressBar()

                    val user = User(firstName, lastName, bio)
                    //profile?.Edit(firstName, lastName, bio)

                    if(uid != null){

                        databaseReference.child(uid).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(){

                            if(it.isSuccessful){

                                uploadProfilePic()
                                val intent = Intent(this@RealEditProfileActivity, BrowseActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            } else {
                                hideProgressBar()
                                Toast.makeText(this@RealEditProfileActivity, "Failed to Update Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                val intent = Intent(this@RealEditProfileActivity, BrowseActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }
                        }
                    }


            }){
                Text(text = "Submit")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showProgressBar() {

        dialog = Dialog(this@RealEditProfileActivity)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_wait)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog.show()

    }
    private fun hideProgressBar(){

        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    private fun uploadProfilePic() {

        imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.drawable.image2}")
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Users/"+ auth.currentUser?.uid+".jpg")
        storageReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener {
            hideProgressBar()
            Toast.makeText(this@RealEditProfileActivity, "Profile successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }.addOnFailureListener{
            hideProgressBar()
            Toast.makeText(this@RealEditProfileActivity, "Failed to Upload Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }

    @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun DefaultPreview() {
        flux99Theme() {
            TxtField()
        }
    }
}`
```

I tried to see where the show progress bar method was and I couldnt see why it was not moving past it. Its supposed to hideprogressbar() but it never does.